# Fire Javascript function after firing validation on ASPxTextboxControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net

i have follwing textbox,

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomer"  Native="true"  CssClass="medium required">
                                                    <ValidationSettings RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ></ValidationSettings>
                                                </dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

when User doesn't enter anything into textbox, inbuilt Required field validation fires. and displays * indicating it is required field
but i want to change some css style to AboveTextbox when RequiredField event is fired.
i mean i want to perform some task when Inbuilt requiredfield Validation fires.
how can i catch or how can i know when Requiredfield validation fires?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it standard ASP.NET markup? It doesn't sound like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox runat="server" ID="txtCustomer"  Native="true"  CssClass="medium required">
    <ValidationSettings RequiredField-IsRequired="true" ></ValidationSettings>
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s, e) { myFunc(); }" />
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```